# PDF, DOC Library on Windows 8 (RT)

Tags: c#, pdf, doc

I'm looking for a Library, SDK to integrate directly PDF,DOC Reader in an Windows Store (Windows RT) application developped in C#.

After some researches, I saw that there are some PDF SDK like Foxit SDK which is very expensive.

If someone already tried a PDF Library, which Library is the best and cheapest?

And is there any possibility to integrate a DOC Reader directly in application instead of opening files with Office Reader?

Comment: Are you looking for a PDF viewer or a PDF generator?

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp is not compatible with Windows RT. iTextSharp requires the System.IO classes and does not take the Windows.Storage classes (System.IO has been replaced by Windows.Storage in WinRT)

I think there are no free pdf libraries available for WinRT.

I work on PDFNet which is very powerful but expensive :

http://www.pdftron.com

Some other paid pdf libraries :

http://www.foxitsoftware.com/mswin8metro
http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/winrt.htm
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt